# Puppeteer setContent - wait both domcontentloaded and networkidle0

Tags: puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to render PDFs from my HTML template, while replacing the placeholders inside the template content prior to calling page.createPDFStream. Some of these placeholders are `src` attributes of the `img` HTML tags (I don't want to to get data and convert it to base64, I prefer to set src attribute instead, trying to use less less memory)

My question is, when I call

```
await page.setContent(htmlContent, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })`
```

should I use `domcontentloaded` or `networkidle0`? I would like to use both (since using just one of them looks like a race condition problem), but I don't see such an option, neither could find out whether `networkidle0` contains `domcontentloaded`

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]? There may be other approaches to optimizing your PDF creation, but it's hard to say without having something to execute and play with. Regarding the `waitUntil` options, see [this](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded) for an explanation. You can use both with an array, but domcontentloaded is guaranteed to complete before networkidle0, so there's no point in using the two together as far as I can tell. I don't know why they provide the array, since it seems to me like domcontentloaded < load < networkidle2 < networkidle0.